# Am I on the right track with my Hex to binary conversion?

Tags: binary, hex, decimal

I have to convert 1357AC.EF from hex to binary. I'm a little confused on what to do. Since it's a has a decimal, do I convert it from hex to decimal doing (1x16^5)+(3x16^4)+(5x16^3)+(7x16^2)+(10x16^1)+12+(14x16^-1)+(15x16^-2) and then convert that to binary by dividing that by 2 and finding the remainder? Or am I making this too hard for myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert each individual hexadigit to its four-bit binary equivalent.
1357AC.EF would be 0001 0011 0101 0111 1010 1100 . 1110 1111

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer I came up with. Because of the decimal I assumed I had to do something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it too hard one hex character is 4 bits e.g. 'A' = '1100'
So just iterate through the string  get a character, look up the binary in a hash or an array, and then concatenate it with the earlier result.